# Can not export hive dat to local "cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' '<EOF>' '<EOF>'"

Tags: hive

My query is `insert overwrite local directory '/home/localfile'`

And what is get is:
 `Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:48 cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in statement (state=42000,code=40000)`

Comment: this is not complete query. it should contain SELECT part

Comment: Generally, it's SemanticException, maybe select some non-existing columns  in your SQL.